# profiling Rebus with rabbitmq has high CPU usage

Tags: rabbitmq, cpu-usage, profiler, rebus

I'm using Rebus to communicate with rabbitmq and I've configured to use 4 workers with 4 max parallelism. Also I notice that the prefetch count is 1 (probably to have an even balancing between consumers).

My issue is happening when I have spike with let's say 1000 messages for instance, i notice high CPU usage on a kubernetes environment with 2 containers where the CPU is limited to let's say 0.5 CPU.

I've profiled the application with dotTrace and it's showing that the cause is at cancenationToken.WaitHandle.wait method inside the DefaultBackOffStrategy class.

My question is if the initial setup of workers/parallelism is making this happen or i need to tweek something in Rebus. I've also tried to change the prefetch count for each consumer but on the rabbitmq management UI this doesn't change the default value (which is one).

Also with the CPU profiler from visual studio and looking at the .net counters I notice some lock contention counters (can this be related)

Why is the CPU usage so high is my question at this point and a way to solve this properly.

Thanks for any help given.

Comment: Umm I am not sure if I understand you correctly, so I apologize if this is off.... but it sounds a little bit like you're wondering why there's high CPU usage when you have lots of messages coming in, but I would actually pretty much expect those things to be correlated (depending on the type of work you're doing when processing each message, of course)

Comment: @mookid8000 No need to apologize :) I'm just trying to understand why the profiler marks that particular method as top cpu usage on the wait method, maybe it's just confusing on my side but I'm actually doing some json manipulation so I was expecting that to be the high cpu usage, not the delivery mechanism (aka Rebus/rabbitmq).it takes 30m to process 1000 messages. I have the same workers as level of parallelism (5), I'm wondering if teeking this settings (increase parallelism or use the TPL version) would improve this. It's weird because even with 100 messages the CPU goes 100% :/

Comment: @Coastpear any update on this? I'm currently seeing this same behavior while set the prefetch count up to 50 and only one consumer, and the difference with not setting any prefetch count it's hitting 110% CPU